# ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CSP In Iframe Of Itch Io.Game

Tags: html, iframe, jekyll, jekyll-theme

I've Making My Website When I Receive A Error On The Iframe, "ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CSP"

It's On Jekyll When I Use The Iframe Of My Game [Play Pong Game 0.0.5 alpha on itch.io](https://isaacjs.itch.io/pg004a) Or [Play IsaacJS Breakout 0.0.1 on itch.io](https://isaacjs.itch.io/isaacjs-breakout-001)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What does blocked:csp mean? You may be seeing blocked:csp in Chrome developer tools when the browser is trying to load a resource. It might show up in the status column as (blocked:csp) CSP stands for Content Security Policy, and it is a browser security mechanism.

[Referance:](https://content-security-policy.com/examples/blocked-csp/)